# Specifying Callbacks for Simulink Block Types

Tags: matlab, callback

I'm trying to figure out how to set a callback for *for every instance of a specific MATLAB object type* and *not* a single instance. In my case the object type is either a SimuLink Block, Subsystem, or ModelReference.

After having read

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html

I tried

```
function openCallback(src, evt)
    disp('here');
end
set(groot, 'defaultBlockOpenFcn', @openCallback);
```

but it fails as

```
Error using matlab.ui.Root/set
blockopenfcn is an invalid class name
```

Is this possible, somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Simulink block callbacks are set using set_param function on a block handle. You would need to set it for a single instance of the block. I do not think it is possible to set it for every instance of a block. If you have a model you can find all the blocks of a type and set their callbacks in a loop.

You can see help for block callbacks at http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/block-callbacks.html. You would call set_param as

```
set_param(gcb, 'OpenFcn', 'disp(''open fcn'')')
```

where gcb is a function that returns currently selected block in a model.